# Add increasing integer Id to a JavaRDD

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I have a simple `JavaRDD<String>` like:

```
("a"),("b"),("c")...
```

Now I want to add an **increasing integer id** to each element. The point is, I want to **define the begin Id myself**, like:

```
("a",5),("b",6),("c",7)...
```

I know `zipWithIndex()` but this method can not set a begin Id number. Maybe I can first do `zipwithIndex()` then do a `map()` to increase the id,But is there another explict way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.zipWithIndex` and then followed by a `map` stating to increase the index with the your user defined value .

eg. `rdd.zipWithIndex.map(a=>(a._1,a._2+userDefinedIndexValue))`

Comment: Can further be reduced to `rdd.zipWithIndex.mapValues(_+userDefinedIndexValue)`